# Verbiage in book, ...uniformly in $\theta$ belonging to compact subsets...

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, asymptotics

I am reading Statistical Estimation and Asymptotic Theory by Ibragimov and Has'minskii and was confused by the following passage:
... and that we have uniformly in $\theta$ belonging to the compact subsets of $\Theta$:
$$\underset{|h|>\epsilon}{\inf}\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} |f(x,\theta+h)-f(x,\theta)|dx >0,\epsilon>0. $$

I understand what the statement implies (that there are no "flat regions" with respect to $\theta$), but not the preceding condition.  What does the passage mean in using "uniformly"?  Does it mean that for compact subsets of $\Theta$, for any $\epsilon$ there exists a $\delta$ such that the above integral is greater than $\delta$?

Comment: Looks like an awkward translation from another language. I can't figure it out'The grammar  of it eludes me.

Comment: It's very strange.  The only apparent limit is the integral, but it would be odd in a statement like this to point out that the integral converges uniformly for all such $\theta$.

Comment: Kind of a statement of the obvious if my interpretation is correct, since the minimum value of the limit integral can  be found for a compact set.